# Swift embedded framework build fails when archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, archive

I have added a swift framework in my project as a sub-project. It works fine when I run on simulator and device. But when I tried to archive the main product it fails with error:

***"/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProductName-bhtbyknuwzpjjwaadaqiytxtzypo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProductName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/MyFramework.framework: No such file or directory"***

I searched for that path and I ended to the folder **"/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProductName-bhtbyknuwzpjjwaadaqiytxtzypo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/ProductName/BuildProductsPath"**
which has only three sub folders:

- Release-iphoneos
- Release-universal
- SwiftSupport

and there is no **"Release-iphonesimulator"** folder.

Here is the build script of the framework:

```
set -e
set +u
# Avoid recursively calling this script.
if [[ $SF_MASTER_SCRIPT_RUNNING ]]
then
exit 0
fi
set -u
export SF_MASTER_SCRIPT_RUNNING=1


# Constants
SF_TARGET_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Take build target
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([A-Za-z]+) ]]
then
SF_SDK_PLATFORM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find platform name from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

#if [[ "$SF_SDK_PLATFORM" = "iphoneos" ]]
#then
#echo "Please choose iPhone simulator as the build target."
#exit 1
#fi

IPHONE_DEVICE_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos

# Build the other (non-simulator) platform
xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${IPHONE_DEVICE_BUILD_DIR}/arm64" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" ARCHS='arm64' VALID_ARCHS='arm64' $ACTION

xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"  CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${IPHONE_DEVICE_BUILD_DIR}/armv7" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" ARCHS='armv7 armv7s' VALID_ARCHS='armv7 armv7s' $ACTION

# Copy the framework structure to the universal folder (clean it first)
rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework"

# Smash them together to combine all architectures
lipo -create  "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/arm64/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/armv7/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

***Note:*** I have commented the following line because archiving is enabled only with a device sdk platform (not simulator)

```
if [[ "$SF_SDK_PLATFORM" = "iphoneos" ]]
then
echo "Please choose iPhone simulator as the build target."
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Make sure that you have added MyFramework.framework to embedded frameworks in build phases of target settings.

Comment: I have already done it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any updates?

Comment: If it still matters to anyone, i had the same problem, turned out my framework didn't have a Distro build configuration and my project was using the Distro build config to Archive. So I just created a Distro build config to the framework and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

- Build for simulator before trying to lipo them together.

  ```
  echo "Building for iPhoneSimulator"
  xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE_PATH}" -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS='i386 x86_64' BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean build
  ```
- Also make sure the output directory exists

  ```
  mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
  ```

  Put this over the comment:

  ```
  #Take build target
  ```